# VoiceRecognition Android Taking Too Long To React

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I'm trying to find a way to get the SpeechRecognizer to react to speech a lot quicker. I have found that the process from onBeginning of speech onwards is pretty fast, but I need the actual reaction to speech meaning onBeginning of speech to have a timelimit before deciding what word is said. Let me know possible suggestions.

Comment: Hi Akash, I am aware of those. What those do is help speed up the process once it hears your voice. My problem is, is that it doesn't hear your voice for at least a second, wondering if that process can be sped up.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isnt very clear but if you want more fine-grained control over when speech should start recording or the minimum length of the speech etc. you can set quite a few extras in the `RecognizerIntent` to customize it to your needs such as

`EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` , `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS` and `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS`.

Read up on these [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).